# css boxShadow javascript change setinterval

Tags: javascript, css

I want to be able to change the boxShadow.  I want it to change every second to a different color.

I have tried this many ways and haven't be able to get this to work.
I would really like it to change between 4 colors but 2 will be ok!

```
<style>
var myVar = setInterval(function () {
    smoke()
}, 1000);

function smoke() {
    if(document.getElementById("profile_description_box").style.boxShadow = "0px 0px 35px #ed47d0") {
        document.getElementById("myDIV").style.boxShadow = "0px 0px 25px #4d4d4d";
    }
    if(document.getElementById("profile_description_box").style.boxShadow = "0px 0px 35px #4d4d4d") {
        document.getElementById("myDIV").style.boxShadow = "0px 0px 35px #ed47d0";
    }
}
</style>
```

Comment: change your `style` section to `script` first.

Comment: have you tried using webkit, moz and other browser specific boxShadhow property??? You also dont need to do function(){smoke()}, just do setInterval(smoke, 1000)

Comment: Can you put your html (just a little bit) cause you use two different ID ("profile_description_box" and "myDiv") and I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly are you html dom elements hence cannot be accurate but the below jsBin works. you need to change to different shadow as per your needs

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/givije/1/edit?html,css,js,console,output#J:L11)

[Improvised](http://jsbin.com/givije/2/edit?html,css,js,console,output#J:L6) contains the working code i.e. the below code works.

```
    var myVar=setInterval(smoke, 1000);

function smoke() {  
  var ele = document.getElementById("profile_description_box");
  var eleBoxShadow = ele.style.boxShadow;
  console.log('calling' + eleBoxShadow);
  if(eleBoxShadow == "red 0px 0px 35px") {
     ele.style.boxShadow = "0px 0px 25px blue";
   }
   else if(eleBoxShadow == "blue 0px 0px 35px") {
      ele.style.boxShadow = "0px 0px 35px red";
   }
  else {
    ele.style.boxShadow = "0px 0px 35px red";
  }
}
```

Few points

- The value of style.boxShadow contains rgb(xx,xx,xx) so your if comparison wont work
- Try using webkit, moz and other browser specific boxShadhow property.
- As hin110531 pointed,  remove style and add script!

Comment: You are repeating the same mistakes the questioner has made.

Comment: Which one were u referring to? Since the value he was comparing to itself was wrong i didn conc on the condition!

Comment: you've just changed all of your `if(eleBoxShadow = "0px 0px 25px #4d4d4d")` statement to `if(eleBoxShadow == "0px 0px 25px #4d4d4d")`···. Asking me which one I'm referring to sounds weird sir. I just want you to know that I'm not trying to blame you for that by the way. And my ID is not hin110531 as well :=

Comment: @hina10531 yeah i got that you were referring to == as i metioned in my previous comment. I meant to know did you refer to anything else apart from == so that i could change that as well! Thanks for letting me know that!

Comment: you guys are close but it doens't change.  it always stays one color.  (yeah i caught the == and the <script> already!  

why isn't is changing to different colors?

Comment: check the improvised jsBin, it is changing. It is not changing for you because the value style.boxShadow returns is different than what you are comparing!

Answer (score 0):

**Your code was almost there** but you made a few mistakes.

---

1. **First, remove `<style>` declaration on yours.**
2. **Second**, **your `if` statement is wrong**. You should use `==` when comparing values.

---

Working code here below for you.

```js
var myVar=setInterval(function () {smoke()}, 1000);

function smoke() {

  if( document.getElementById("profile_description_box").style.boxShadow == "" ) {
    
    document.getElementById("myDIV").style.boxShadow = "0px 0px 25px skyblue";
    document.getElementById("profile_description_box").style.boxShadow = "0px 0px 35px red";     
    
  } else if ( document.getElementById("profile_description_box").style.boxShadow == "0px 0px 35px red" ) {
    
    document.getElementById("myDIV").style.boxShadow = "0px 0px 35px blue";
    document.getElementById("profile_description_box").style.boxShadow = "0px 0px 35px orange";
    
  } else if ( document.getElementById("profile_description_box").style.boxShadow == "0px 0px 35px orange" ) {
    
    document.getElementById("myDIV").style.boxShadow = "0px 0px 35px skyblue";
    document.getElementById("profile_description_box").style.boxShadow = "0px 0px 35px red";
    
  }
}
```

```css
#profile_description_box {
  padding:50px;
}

#myDIV {
  height:100px;  
}
```

```html
<div id="profile_description_box">

   <div id="myDIV"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is how i got it to work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
#myDIV {
position: absolute;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: coral;
color: white;
box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px blue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>Click the "Try it" button to set the boxShadow property of the DIV element:</p>
Test: <span id="ttest">1</span>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="myDIV">
<h1>myDIV</h1>
</div>

<script>
var myVar=setInterval(function () {smoke()}, 1000);

function smoke() {
var a = document.getElementById("ttest").innerHTML;
var b = +a + 1;
document.getElementById("ttest").innerHTML = b;

if( a == 1 ) {
document.getElementById("myDIV").style.boxShadow = "10px 10px 10px blue";
}
if( a == 7 ) {
document.getElementById("myDIV").style.boxShadow = "10px 10px 10px red";
}
if( a == 13 ) {
document.getElementById("myDIV").style.boxShadow = "10px 10px 10px black";
}
if( a == 19 ) {
document.getElementById("myDIV").style.boxShadow = "10px 10px 10px   skyblue";
}
if( a == 29 ) {
document.getElementById("myDIV").style.boxShadow = "10px 10px 10px red";
document.getElementById("ttest").innerHTML = "1";
}
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```